# Nginx+Gunicorn - reverse proxy not working

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, flask-restful, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup a python flask application on a server following this guide:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04.  I have this working running on my local machine by following the guide. However when I am trying to implement on the actual server with the same config I am running into an issue on proxying requests back to the gunicorn server. I am able to serve static content from Nginx with no problem. When I make a web service call from the static content back to Nginx, it should be proxied back to the gunicorn server.

For example when I try to make the call 'http://example.com/rest/webService', I would expect Nginx to pass anything starting with /rest/ back to gunicorn. The error below is all I can see in the error logs about what is happening:

2019/01/18 12:48:18 [error] 2930#2930: *18 open() "/var/www/html/rest/webService" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ip_address, server: example.com, request: "GET /rest/webService HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"

Here is the setup for python_app:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location ^/rest/(.*)$ {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/python_app/python_app.sock;
    } }
```

The only change to my nginx.conf file was to change 'include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*' to 'include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/python_app'.

Please let me know if you have any ideas at all on what I may be missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but some questions....

If you run

```
sudo systemctl status myproject
```

Do you see affirmation that gunicorn is running, and what socket it is bound to?

And does

```
sudo nginx -t
```

come back saying no diagnostic?

The regex in the location block for nginx -- I don't see anything similar to that in the guide, I see that you're trying to capture everything after "rest/", but looking at the nginx documents, I think you'd have to have $1 to reference the captured part of the URL.  Can you try without the "^/rest/(.*)$" and see whether nginx finds anything?

Is the group that owns your directory a group that nginx is part of (a lot of setups are www-data)